# How to use number_format correctly?

Tags: php

I am trying to get query to format correctly.

I need all results to have '`$`' in front and anything less than 300 to add '`/mo.*`' to the end.  It isn't doing what I would like. Any advise? Thanks in advance!

```
public function get_under300_specials() {
    $this->db->select(' vehicle_specials.type, vehicle_specials.stock_number, inventory.year, inventory.make, inventory.model, inventory.trim, vehicle_specials.price, vehicle_specials.msrp, vehicle_specials.was, vehicle_specials.description, inventory.photos')->from('vehicle_specials')->join('inventory', 'inventory.stock_number = vehicle_specials.stock_number');

    $this->db->where("vehicle_specials.price < 300");
    $this->db->where('status','active');
    //return $this->db->get();

    $results = $this;
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) { // Format number
        $results[$key]['price'] = '$' . number_format($result['price']) . (($result['price'] < 300) ? '/mo.*' : '');
    }
    return $results->db->get();
}
```

Comment: what, pray tell, would you like it to do. Or shall we all guess?

Comment: What is the expected format?

Comment: It seems fine here. What values have you checked?

Comment: I've tried several. Everything is just coming out numerical, with no $ or /mo.* .

Comment: I think that return $results->db->get(); maybe cause the problem. What does the get() method?

Comment: you not returning your formatted numbers, but something else  (the originals?)

Comment: Thats what it appears to be. How should i return the formatted numbers instead of the original?

Comment: When i simply 'result $results;' I get nothing but a blank page. No error, just blank.

Comment: I think that $results returned fine but somewhere else in your code a foreach using them crashes because it expects different format. Set error_reporting ON and see what happens.

Comment: What framework are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what framework you're working with, i assume the problem is you're not getting data from database before you're already trying to format it.

```
public function get_under300_specials() {
    $this->db->select(' vehicle_specials.type, vehicle_specials.stock_number, inventory.year, inventory.make, inventory.model, inventory.trim, vehicle_specials.price, vehicle_specials.msrp, vehicle_specials.was, vehicle_specials.description, inventory.photos')->from('vehicle_specials')->join('inventory', 'inventory.stock_number = vehicle_specials.stock_number');

    $this->db->where("vehicle_specials.price < 300");
    $this->db->where('status','active');

    $results = $this->db->get(); // this might require a table to get data from

    // assuming get()-method returns array, not object
    // futher more, if there is 'price' field already in object, it would be good practice to not to overwrite it if not necessary. Thus, using price_str

    foreach ($results as $key => &$result) { // Format number
        $result['price_str'] = '$' . number_format($result['price']);
        if( intval($result['price']) < 300 )
            $result['price_str'] .= "/mo.*"; 
    }

    return $results;
}
```